# Prevent rails 404, 500 pages from rendering inside layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web app which has a global layout file (application.html.erb).
When I encounter a 404 or 500 error the corresponding error page is rendered inside the layout file.

I want to prevent this from happening and render outside the layout but I can't figure out where to put the render :layout => false call. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the super exeption notifier plugin which has built in supprt for rendering error templates.